# How can I find the rows that match the first word of another row in another table?

Tags: mysql

What I want to do is select some rows from interv where the first word in interv.Ordeds is equal to the first word in drugs.Products. Where this is true I would like to update interv.Generic with the values of drugs.Generic (but I didnt get that far before getting an error), this is how far I got, please help if you can:

```
select * from
interv 
left outer join drugs on ((SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `OrderS` , ' ', 1 ) 
FROM `interv`) = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( `ProductD` , ' ', 1 ) FROM `drugs`))
```

When I do this I get error :
Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Side note : I would also settle for having a certain amount of characters in interv.Orders be equal to certain amount of characters in drugs.Products but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with a like statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just by using `substring_index()` in the `on` clause:

```
select *
from interv i left outer join
     drugs d
     on substring_index(Orders, ' ', 1) = substring_index(ProductD, ' ', 1);
```

If you want to do this in an `update` query:

```
update interv i join
       drugs d
       on substring_index(Orders, ' ', 1) = substring_index(ProductD, ' ', 1)
    set i.Generic = d.Generic;
```

EDIT:

You have multiple first words in each table that are the same.  You can see these by doing:

```
select substring_index(Orders, ' ', 1) as word, count(*) as cnt
from drugs
group by substring_index(Orders, ' ', 1) 
having cnt > 1
order by cnt desc, word;
```

And then a similar query on the other table.

Comment: I tried this but out of a 2771 row database its returning 29000 results so im guessing there are duplicates, any idea why?